# Why is it so much quicker for MongoDB documents to be read compared to Sql Table Rows?

Tags: sql, mongodb, bigdata

I'm thinking about converting a sql table of mine into a mongo db collection with each row of my sql table being a mongodb document. I wondering if it really is worth it if I don't have a ton of data. I like working with MongoDB more than Sql but I am curious if I would actually see a performance increase. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know about whether the performance is better or worse, then you need to try both systems on your data and similar hardware.

There are efficiencies that NO-SQL databases offer, because they are not [ACID-compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), they do not offer full relational support for querying, for other reasons.  However, SQL databases can often offer comparable performance, through the use of indexes, in-memory data structures, and partitioning schemes.  And, SQL is often better for complex, ad hoc queries.  (I'm trying to be neutral in my descriptions . . . different software has different strengths, regardless of my personal biases.)

If you are more comfortable using MongoDB and do not want to use this project to learn new database technology, then that is a very good reason for using MongoDB, assuming it is an appropriate tool.